Lean4: Prove that ∑ ii : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑ii) = ∑ x : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑x) (sums over Fin n)
Im working with sums over Fin n for some n : Nat, and I am stuck with two sums, that should be equal (and look exactly equal in lean4 infoview), but I do not know how to prove that.
I am stuck with the goal
⊢ ↑xz = ↑xz - ∑ ii : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑ii) + ∑ x : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑x).
It would be sufficient to prove that  ∑ ii : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑ii)  =  ∑ x : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑x).
Minimal working example:
import Mathlib
import Mathlib.Algebra.BigOperators.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.Nat.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.Nat.Choose.Basic
import Mathlib.Tactic.Basic
open BigOperators
open Nat

lemma lemma1 {n m: Nat} {k : Fin n → Nat}  {xz : Fin (∑ i : Fin n, k i)}  :
 ∃ j : (Fin (n)) , ∃ m : Fin ( k  j), xz =( ∑ i1 : Fin j.val, k ( Fin.castLE (Fin.is_lt j) i1)) + m := by
induction n with
| zero =>
  /-
  some code
  -/
  sorry

| succ nn ih =>
  let  q := ∑ ii : Fin nn, k ( Fin.castLE (Fin.is_lt nn) ii) ;
  match le_or_lt q ( xz.val)  with
  |Or.inl q_leq_x =>

    use Fin.mk nn (Nat.lt_succ_self nn)


    have x_minus_q_le_knn : xz - q < k (Fin.mk nn (Nat.lt_succ_self nn)):=
      by sorry

    use Fin.mk (xz-q) x_minus_q_le_knn

    ring_nf
    rw[add_comm]

    -- ∑ ii : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑ii) and ∑ x : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE _ ↑↑x) are equal. How to prove that?
    -- this rewritte fails
    rw[sub_add_cancel]
    sorry

  | Or.inr x_le_q =>
    /-
  some code
  -/
    sorry


I can’t reproduce your example in https://live.lean-lang.org/.  However sometimes for these sorts of problems it helps to change the pretty printer settings.  Do #help option to see the available options.  set_option pp.all true is the nuclear option that shows all the details, but sometimes it is too verbose.

Also see https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/715/122 for advice on these sorts of cases.

Note that, in general, it is not true that a - b + b = a, because that parenthesis like so (a - b) + b. For instance, consider 2 - 3 + 3 = (2 - 3) + 3 = 0 + 3 = 3. That's because difference between natural numbers cannot produce negative numbers in Lean, and so if a < b, a - b = 0.

@jthulhu They can address that using rw [sub_add_cancel q_leq_x] (where q_leq_x : q ≤ ↑xz).

I tried set_option pp.proofs true. (Lean normally hides proof terms in goals with ....) I see (in my modified version of your code) that I get the following goal after rw [sub_add_cancel q_leq_x]: ∑ x : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE (Fin.is_lt ⟨nn, lt_succ_self nn⟩) ↑↑x) = ∑ ii : Fin nn, k (Fin.castLE (Fin.is_lt ↑nn) ↑↑ii). It isn't a problem that the proof terms are different. Proofs of the same Prop are definitionally equal in Lean.  But hovering over the proofs (which you could even do without pp.proofs), shows they are different Props: ↑⟨nn, lt_succ_self nn⟩ < nn + 1 vs ↑↑nn < nn + 1.

It isn't pretty but I solved it.  Here is my proof starting at ring_nf:
    ring_nf
    have sub_lemma (x y y1 : ℕ) (h : y <= x) (h2 : y1 = y) : x = y1 + (x - y) := by
      rw [h2, Nat.add_comm, Nat.sub_add_cancel h]
    apply sub_lemma
    . exact q_leq_x
    . rw [(by rfl : q = ∑ ii : Fin nn, k ( Fin.castLE (Fin.is_lt nn) ii))]
      have h : (↑nn : Fin nn.succ) = ⟨nn, lt_succ_self nn⟩ := by
        simp
        congr
      rw [h]

Here sub_lemma is just a basic fact about Nat subtraction that you need.  Then to prove the two terms are equal, we need to show h.
(My simp; congr is bad form.  One shouldn't do simp if it isn't closing the goal.  I'll let you fix up the proof.)
As for how I found this, see my comments on your question.
